# Expression blend solutions won't open in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, expression-blend, compatibility

My key tools are Photoshop, Illustrator and Expression Blend. As much as I love the user interaction of Blend I'm finding problems when I open a Visual Studio file in Blend created by the developer. The same goes for the developer as when he tried to open my files it comes up with an error message.

I understand Blend 3 is fairly new. Does anyone know of any fixes that might solve these problems?

Thanks
Judi

Comment: What versions of Blend and VS? What's the error message you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These might be bugs. You can file them at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback